# Integral of data with time (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a time series `x(t)` that is a NumPy array. My assignment tells me that I need to find the integral of this data with time.

How am I supposed to do this? It's not a function that I need to integrate, it's a list of data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the statement of the problem. A rude approach would be something like this

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

t = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
x = t*t

delta = t[1] - t[0]
I = sum(delta*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Simpson's Rule*.  A routine that does that for you is `simps` in `scipy.integrate`. If there aren't regular intervals between your data for integration, you should choose a different method from `scipy.integrate`, such as the trapezoidal rule `trapz`.

```
>>> help(scipy.integrate.simps)
Help on function simps in module scipy.integrate.quadrature:

simps(y, x=None, dx=1, axis=-1, even='avg')
    Integrate y(x) using samples along the given axis and the composite
    Simpson's rule.  If x is None, spacing of dx is assumed.

    If there are an even number of samples, N, then there are an odd
    number of intervals (N-1), but Simpson's rule requires an even number
    of intervals.  The parameter 'even' controls how this is handled.
```